# Apply a plugin to the posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin for wordpress. It's successfully installed in my site but in order to show it in the client section I have to call the function (function that applies the plugin portion) manually. How can I force my plugin to appear in every posts?

Answer (score 1):

Read it in wordpress plugin development part in wordrepss.org. For this you need to use [Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters)

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter the_content which is a filter on the body of the article  - check out the many web articles on this and it should start to make sense.